# SVN | WordPress Repository download

Tags: wordpress, svn, repository

I like to download the files from this URL : http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk by using the SVN. The broblem is that the URL does not seem to be correct for download.

I have try to use the following command in my Command Line:

```
svn co http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tests/trunk/ .
```

but I am getting the following error:

```
svn: E175003: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://core.trac.wordpress.org/tests'
svn: E175003: The OPTIONS response did not includ the requested activity-collection-set; this often means that the URL is not WebDAV-enabled
```

Can somebody to help me find out what is the correct URL to use with SVN ? or how can I download this repository ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trac URL never was and never will be URL of real repository

According to [Subversion Access](http://wordpress.org/download/svn/) page

> To check out the latest WP codebase, try this checkout command:
>
> svn co http://core.svn.wordpress.org/trunk/

And you can try to predict final full URL of interesting part of repo or find it in web-browser or repo-browser